# Is the image of this regular map open, closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a question from Shafarevich that I'm trying to figure out.
It asks if the image of $f(x,y,z)=(x,xy,xyz)$ is open or closed (in relation to the Zariski Topology)...I think it is neither but I'm having a hard time proving it.

Comment: Dear David, Have you tried plotting it taking $x,y,z$ to be real numbers?  Regards,

Comment: So if we plot it, we get everything except for the yz and xz plane plus the origin?

Comment: Dear David, your description of the image is not quite correct since the whole of the $x$-axis is in the image although it is in the $x,z$, plane which you claim not to be in the image.

Answer (score 7):

The image $I$ is not open because its trace on the plane $P=\{x=0\}$ is not open in $P$: indeed, $P\cap I=\{(0,0,0)\}\subset P$ .
The image $I$ is not closed because it is dense (since it contains the open subset $x\neq0,y\neq 0, z\neq 0$) but is not the whole of $\mathbb A^3_k$ : indeed, $(0,1,1)\notin I$ .

**Edit: the beauty of the Zariski topology**
I have implicitly used above that $\mathbb A^3_k$ is irreducible (because the corresponding coordinate ring $k[X,Y,Z]$ is a domain) and thus that, amazingly,  **each** of its non-empty open  subsets is dense.
Such are  the charms of the sometimes unfairly criticized Zariski topology!

Comment: I am answering this question in order to show that algebraic geometry also consists of quite down-to-earth calculations, and not only of abstract  difficult oncepts. Even determining the image $I$ can be difficult for beginners who haven't done enough elementary calculations.

Comment: I am self-studying Shafarevich's book (absolute beginner level) and I don't understand how this question could be answered using only the knowledge obtained from the pages preceding it: it is not clear to me why $(0,0,0)$ is not open in $P$, and why open subsets of the affine space should be dense. I am talking about [problems 6 and 7 from the 2012 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=tyK4BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33), the same as [problems 8 and 9 from the 1977 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=m6nwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA22).